# Display the position and total when dragging and dropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Handle empty lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
    #sortable1,
    #sortable2,
    #sortable3 {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background: #eee;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 143px;
    }
    #sortable1 li,
    #sortable2 li,
    #sortable3 li {
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      width: 120px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul"
      });

      $("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        dropOnEmpty: false
      });

      $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 5</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 10</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 12</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 13</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 14</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 15</li>
  </ul>
  <br style="clear:both">
</body>
</html>
```

As I mentioned above at the end of each Column the number of rows must be displayed and aside of each row numbering should be displayed.

```
1 worker1     1 worker8           1 worker14
2 worker2     2 worker10          2 worker13
3 worker3     3 worker11          3 worker15
4 worker4     4 worker12           total 3
5 worker5     total 4
6 worker7
7 worker6
8 worker9
Total 8
```

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) The layout you're trying to achieve doesn't make sense. Can you describe how the numbers related to each `Worker`

Comment: I just an example I tried to show they will be in the next column as in the code. And it is sorting of workers position respective to working in particular machines. I need to drag and drop if they change their position.

Comment: What will be in the next column? Again - it makes no sense. Why does the first column only have 3 items and the second 4? What about the other 8?

Comment: 1 Worker1       1 worker 4          1 worker 8
2 Worker2       2 worker 5          2 worker 9 
3 Worker3       3 worker 6          3 worker 10
                4 worker 7          4 worker 11
Total 3         Total 4             5 worker 12
         6 worker 13
         7 worker 14
         8 worker 15
         
         Total 8

Comment: So now the last problem to solve is *why* is there 3/4/8 items in each column? Come on, all this should be in the question. If you want people to help you give them all the information.

Comment: It is a drag and drop feature. If you look at the code you can understand. I can rearrange the workers in each column. I can drag and drop them from one column to another. or change position in each column.

Comment: Should the totals be a part of each list or a separate element after each list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you could wrap the `ul` elements in a `div` with another `div` under them to hold the total count of `li` elements within that container. You can then updated that `total` when an item is dropped using the `stop` property of the sortable plugin, like this:

```js
$("ul.droptrue").sortable({
  connectWith: "ul",
  stop: function() {
    $('.total').text(function() {
      return 'Total: ' + $(this).closest('.container').find('li').length;
    });
  }
});

$("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
  connectWith: "ul",
  dropOnEmpty: false
});

$("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
#sortable1,
#sortable2,
#sortable3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 143px;
}
#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li,
#sortable3 li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0.8em; /* changed so the example fits in the snippet better*/
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="container">
  <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 5</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="total">Total: 5</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 10</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="total">Total: 5</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 12</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 13</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 14</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Worker 15</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="total">Total: 5</div>
</div>
```